# Timeline & iFrame

Tags: facebook, facebook-timeline

Can anybody guide about how 
does the new FB timeline incorporate the iframe for its pages.
Or is there any new stuffs coming in to replace these stufs?

Answer (score 0):

The way you create and display your iFrame will be the same, except for a size change.

The new iFrame will be 810px wide, instead of 520px - existing tabs (apps) that are set to 520px will just be centered on the page, so they aren't "broken." Giving us 290 extra pixels is great!

You can no longer set a tab as "default landing page". Instead, users always see the main Timeline view and have to actively click through to custom apps.

To edit which apps you display, click the drop-down icon to the right of the tiles, click the ‘+’ button to import your custom apps, and then hover over them and click the pencil to swap them around.

If you have a contest or something on a tab which you would have wanted set as the "default landing page", you can create a post on your page which has a few sentences advertising such, with a link to the tab. You can then "pin" this post to the top of your page, so it will be the first thing users read. "Pinning" and "starring" on your Page act exactly like they do on your personal timeline.

[Here's a good explanation of all changes](http://techcrunch.com/2012/02/29/how-to-use-timeline-for-pages/)